# Cart link from quote ID

Tags: api

Is it possible to get a cart link from a quote ID create from the magento API. ie I want to add items to the cart using the magento API that would be initiated from a 3rd party website. And when they are ready to check out id have provided them a link to their magento cart.

Comment: I am trying to the same exact thing... Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.create.html

```
Returns:

Type    Description
int     ID of the created empty shopping cart
```

You would have to create your own link and controller to reload the cart. Take a look at [Programmatically add items to cart and assign to guest user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30417/programmatically-add-items-to-cart-and-assign-to-guest-user/30434#30434)

Comment: Ya I am using that api call as well as http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html to add items to the cart. Though with the quote id I get back from the cart create I am trying to create a link to a cart a user could hit in the browser.

Comment: Will your 3rd party website send an email to the customer?

Comment: All you need is to create a custom module in magento with a controller that will reload (see link above) the quote from the id in your email

Comment: It wont email the customer. would that matter? when they checkout, they'll check out in magento.

Comment: I looked at that link. In the code: `code` $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quote_id');
 $store_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id');

 ....   
 $this->_getSession()->clear();
 $this->_getQuote()
      ->setQuoteId($id)
      ->setStoreId($store_id)
      ->setIsActive(true)
      ->load($id);/`code`  ... in what context is "this" object. ie what type of object is this. "`code` $this = Mage::app() `/code` " ??

Comment: Since your using the magento api, which will be executing server side remotely, How will you link a customer with a cart?

Comment: This is the essence of my question. My thought,and maybe there is a bad assumption here, is I'll be adding a cart as a guest. They can get a link that could take them to a cart and they continue to purchase as a guest or login and and continue their purchase. Is this possible?

Comment: I know `$url = Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart');` will get me a url. however I know there is some calls I would need to do get the cart loaded with the quote id. `setQuoteId($id); ` is part of it. I just dont know if it all relates and/or possible.

Answer (score 1):

ricv,
first, you want to add product using using soap api for third party site:

`1.create quote:`http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.create.html

`2.add Product in quote:`http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html

If,`your is register customer ,then  Allows you to move products from the current quote to a customer quote`.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.moveToCustomerQuote.html

Comment: Thank you. I am currently doing steps 1 and 2. Though I am confused on the difference between a quote to a customer quote? And is this necessary to get a link to a shopping cart in magento I can direct users to?

Answer (score 0):

Standard cart link for Magento is always the same {site_url}/checkout/cart/, you can create it by using:

`Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/index')`

Comment: That would be code written on the server serving the instance of magento. But i dont see the link between the quote id I would get from cart create via a rest call initiated on a 3rd party website to and a new browser session that i could link to.