# How to copy one quote (only cart items) to other quote (only items )

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, quote

i want to copy one quote (only cart items) to other  quote (only items ).
Only want `to copy cart products to  other new quote`.

Suppose: i have old quote,which id is 5,have 4 items

```
 i have another quote which id 77, have 1 item, i want to copy  4 items of quote id  5 to 
quote id  77.
```

I have try below blog;
[Programmatically add items to cart and assign to guest user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30417/programmatically-add-items-to-cart-and-assign-to-guest-user)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the `merge()` method in [Mage_Sales_Model_Quote](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/5345da52778cc6f5f31938ffd21fccfdd353435c/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php#L1746). I've never used it, but it should be something such as:

```
$quoteA = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load('5');
$quoteB = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load('77');

$quoteB->merge($quoteA);

// Also?
$quoteB->collectTotals()->save();

Zend_Debug::dump($quoteB->getAllItems());
```

// edit - I looked at what Magento does in the checkout session model, and it also calls collectTotals() and save(), so that's probably necessary as well.

Have a look also at [Mage_Checkout_Model_Session](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/5345da52778cc6f5f31938ffd21fccfdd353435c/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php#L202)

Comment: All data is saved in quote tables successfully after merge. But the checkout/cart page shows that 'Cart is empty'. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hi @Arvind07, Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to this, to get the quote items copied over, you need to run the following:

```
foreach($quoteA->getItemsCollection() as $item) {

   $item->setId(null); //Remove the item id, so it gets added
   $quoteB->addItem($item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I wanted to create a new quote in the user's session and copy previous items to it, and it worked for me.

```
$newQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->merge($quote);
$newQuote->setStoreId($quote->getStoreId());
$newQuote->collectTotals()->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->replaceQuote($newQuote);
```