# Programmatically create cart for guest user

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, quote

I have been trying to create cart for **guest** users. But when i create cart **grand_total,sub_total, and item price** fields are not being updated. Those fields have 0.00 in quote table.

This is the code i have been using to create cart.

```
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product=$productModel->load($productId)->setStoreId($store);

           $quote_obj  = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store);

            $param = array(
            'product' => $product->getId(),
            'qty' => $qty,
        );
            $request    = new Varien_Object();
            $request->setData($param);



            try{
                $quote_obj->addProduct($product, $request);
                $quote_obj->collectTotals()->save();   


            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                $this->_critical("Product can't be added to shopping cart",Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
            }
```

I have no idea why this code is not setting grand_total or item price. Any help will be appreciated.

I tried this : [Programmatically add items to cart and assign to guest user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30417/programmatically-add-items-to-cart-and-assign-to-guest-user)

But this also not setting the grand total or any other prices.

My quote table

[image]

Comment: Did you find solution please update the answer..